# Open local HTML file from code in Qt on Mac OSx

Tags: macos, qt, path, qdir, qurl

Hello i am facing a small issue with Qt on the Mac OSX.

So in my program i am trying to open a local `.html` file located in the same path as the application.

Given that Qt is cross-platform , my attempt worked for both Windows and Ubuntu and i assumed that OSX should not have an issue since it is Unix based.

This is my attmpet

```
void MainWindow::openBrowser(bool)
{
    QString link = QDir::currentPath()+"/index.html"; // rename the file

    if(! QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(link.trimmed())))
    {
        displayMessage("Access Error", "Unable to open a file");
    }
}
```

The OSX cannot find the same `index.html` file and I am not sure why.
Is there a better way to concatenate the path?

Comment: when you say *same path as the application.*, do you mean next to the executable or the source code?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yeah sorry, its in the same path as the executable

Comment: Print link and tell me what you get

Comment: so link actually prints the right directory, in my case this is it
`"/Users/user1/Test/project/examples/exmp1/index.html"`
My executable is in this folder as well, thats why i'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MacOS, `QUrl` works using FQ name (`file://absolute_file.name`) and this should be the portable syntax on all platforms.
this can be invoked like this:

```
if(! QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:" + link.trimmed()))) // windows does not like :// 
    {
        qDebug() << "Access Error", "Unable to open a file";
    }
```

Although not needed for local html files,  Qt uses this entry in `Info.plist` for external URLs:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<!-- NOTE! For more information, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33-->
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: thanks Mohammad for clarifying! This worked and it also worked on my Linux machines as well.